# barcode generation in html using php giving same value

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery, barcode

i am using js barcode generation to generate barcode in my PHP website, in the page I have multiple invoices and each one should have unique barcode, my code is like below:

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.5/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>

<?php foreach($catil as $val){?>

<div class="col-4">
  <svg class="barcode"></svg>
  <script>
    JsBarcode(".barcode", "<?=$val->batchnumber?>");
  </script>

</div>

<?php}?>
```

however this is generating same barcode for all inoices even though the batchnumber column is unique for all the invoices, can anyone please tell me what is wrong in here, thanks in advance

Comment: Hi. In your generated HTML, what do you get? Do you get different `JsBarcode(".barcode", "XXX")` values?

Comment: @AlexandreElshobokshy no, i get same value, which is the batchnumber of the last column in the table

Comment: Problem is this `".barcode"` is not unique, so it will generate the same code for all barcodes

Comment: @mplungjan i get correct values for other fields, only when it comes to this barcode i am getting error

Comment: @CarstenLøvboAndersen can you please tell me how to fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your element selector needs to be unique

Assuming batchnumber is unique You can fix it like this

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsbarcode@3.11.5/dist/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>

<?php 
foreach($catil as $val){
$batchnumber = $val->batchnumber;
?>

<div class="col-4">
  <svg id="B_<?=$batchnumber?>"></svg>
  <script>
    JsBarcode("#B_<?=$batchnumber?>", "<?=$batchnumber?>");
  </script>

</div>

<?php}?>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this:

I would add your barcode as a data attribute to the svg like,

```
<?php foreach($catil as $val){?>
<div class="col-4">
  <svg class="barcode" data-barcode="<?=$val->batchnumber?>"></svg>

</div>
<?php}?>
```

Then after all the bar codes has been generated then run this jquery code.

```
$(".barcode").each(function() {
  $(this).JsBarcode($(this).data("barcode"));
});
```

**Demo**

```js
$(".barcode").each(function() {
  $(this).JsBarcode($(this).data("barcode"));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/jsbarcode/3.3.20/JsBarcode.all.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-4">
  <svg class="barcode" data-barcode="hi"></svg>

</div>
<div class="col-4">
  <svg class="barcode" data-barcode="test"></svg>

</div>
```

Comment: @BOOKTHEPARTY Inspect the html page in your browser and look at the svgs, do you see anything inside `data-barcode`

Comment: @BOOKTHEPARTY I don't know much about php but it might have to be `data-barcode="<?php echo $val->batchnumber?>"`

Comment: no, id ont see any error also, it just give me blank space